# Is there a way to dynamically retrieve the height of iframes with different domain names without using postMessage?

Tags: javascript, iframe

```
<script>
    function resizeIframe() {
        var iframe = document.getElementById('iframeContent');
        if (iframe) {
            var iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
            var contentHeight = Math.max(iframeDocument.body.scrollHeight, iframeDocument.documentElement.scrollHeight);
            iframe.style.height = contentHeight + 'px';
        }
    }

    window.addEventListener('load', resizeIframe);
    window.addEventListener('resize', resizeIframe);

</script>
```

It didn't work for me because the domain names are different, and I don't have access to the iframe's code, so I cannot use postMessage.

Comment: Short answer: no. Long answer to meet min length requirement: noooooooooooooooo